# Android while loop in asyntask on UiThread

Tags: android, android-asynctask, ui-thread

I am working on App, in which i have 3 imageview and i want to do these imagesviews changes in loop continuously.

Comment: Question is not clear, redefine your problem. btw No need of `runOnUIThread` in `onPreExecute()` since, `onPreExecute()` itself runs on ui thread.

Comment: If i understand your problem correctly, then you want to make something like loading screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you can do is, in `doInBackground()` you need to call `publishProgress()` that will result in a callback to `onProgrssUpdate()`, In `onProgressUpdate()`, you can make the currentlyVisible imageView to invisible and make next imageView visible.

Answer (score 1):

onPostExecute() and onPreExecute() are running on UI thread already. For communicating in Background you could use onProgressUpdate or send Handler messages to ImageView to safely communicate.

Here is good example of Lars Vogel http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html